# jQuery Put error under form input?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Hello I am just starting out using jQuery I could use a hand with a project.

We are setting up a budget assistant where there will be about 20 items list with a text box beside each item. Then there will be the total showing up at the bottom in a span.

I am pretty close here but I would like to get the errors to show up just below each text input as opposed to at the bottom.

I’m sure this is possible but I have not been able to figure out how. I have been looking online for fixes but no luck so far

Can somebody take a look and let me know?

I would greatly appreciate the help!

```
 <div width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
<div>
    <div width="40px">1</div>
    <div>Butter</div>
    <div><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>Cheese</div>
    <div><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>Eggs</div>
    <div><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>Milk</div>
    <div><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>Bread</div>
    <div><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>Soap</div>
    <div><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt"/></div>
</div>
<div id="summation">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div align="right">Sum :</div>
    <div align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></div>
</div>
 </div>



 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Setup this Fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ocbLfLm2/ It's not clear from your description what exactly is not working. Are you talking about just the format of the page?

Comment: it is working, I would like to move the error under the form. I updated the jsfiddle to show you. I have not used it in a while but I can see it here.

Comment: I can't find your update. When you update it, it may have forked it. Please comment with the URL of your Update.

Comment: Also, what "error" do you mean. Your script does not indicate that it generates an error.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ocbLfLm2/12/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=ocbLfLm2

Comment: When you put a space inside one of the text fields it says.   Sum :
NaN

Comment: I have not been allowing a Space or Letter to be passed: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ocbLfLm2/13/ I am using `var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);` and `if (parseInt(key))`

Answer (score 0):

I made a few guesses based on what you might be doing. I figured you'd only want numbers entered, but those could be Int or Float. Example 2 or 4.95. But an error should appear when any other character is entered and the calculation should not be performed. See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ocbLfLm2/16/

**HTML**

```
<div width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
  <div class="itemWrap">
    <div>1</div>
    <label>Butter</label>
    <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt[]" />
  </div>
  <div class="itemWrap">
    <div>2</div>
    <label>Cheese</label>
    <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt[]" />
  </div>
  <div class="itemWrap">
    <div>3</div>
    <label>Eggs</label>
    <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt[]" />
  </div>
  <div class="itemWrap">
    <div>4</div>
    <label>Milk</label>
    <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt[]" />
  </div>
  <div class="itemWrap">
    <div>5</div>
    <label>Bread</label>
    <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt[]" />
  </div>
  <div class="itemWrap">
    <div>6</div>
    <label>Soap</label>
    <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt[]" />
  </div>
  <div id="summation" class="itemWrap">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <label style="text-align: right;">Sum :</label>
    <div style="width: 50px; text-align: center;"><span id="sum">0.00</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.itemWrap {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #E8DCFF;
  width: 170px;
}

.itemWrap * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.itemWrap div:first-child {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.itemWrap label {
  width: 50px;
}

.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.txt {
  border: default;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".txt").keyup(function(e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    console.log("Key Code:", e.which, "Key:", key);
    if (parseInt(key) || e.which == 8 || e.which == 9 || e.which == 190) {
      $(this).parent(".itemWrap").removeClass("error");
      calculateSum();
    } else {
      $(this).parent(".itemWrap").addClass("error");
    }
  });
});

function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function(k, v) {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN($(v).val()) && $(v).val().length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat($(v).val());
    }
  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

I made adjustments to the HTML only due my personal preference and experience. I added some CSS just for example. The JQuery is really what you're after.

Since you are using `onKeyUp`, I grabbed the `event` so I could look at the key that was pressed. I convert from the charCode to a keyStroke (e.g: 65 -> A). I can then use `parseInt()` to see if the keyStroke was a letter or a number. I also want to allow Tab, Delete, and '.', you will see those added as in the comparison. If all conditions are met, I remove `error` class in case the previous entry generated an error, and then run the calculation.

Hope that helps.

**Updated After Comments**

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ocbLfLm2/19/

Added the following:

```
  <div class="itemWrap">
    <div>1</div>
    <label>Butter</label>
    <input class="txt" type="text" name="txt[]" />
    <div class="errorText">Must be a number</div>
  </div>
```

So now you can add the text you like. and then you use `.show()` and `.hide()` as needed. I also added space via `height: 2.5em;` in the CSS.

Comment: That is the right idea!

Would it be possible to remove the red stroke and add in a text logo below like the one I sent with the blue background?
  
And make the new label you provide stay the same color it is red on my end. I sent the screencap.
http://postimg.org/image/ihq1qpx9b/   http://postimg.org/image/5h0c8pzaj/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this! I think everything is looking great now. Is there a way to remove the NaN tag here?  I don't see it anywhere. http://postimg.org/image/ggsr7frwd/

Comment: @Biggy It's not clear what you're doing from a screen shot. I would advise looking over what you're doing or open a new question. If I have addressed your orignal question, I hope that it helps you and you will upvote and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Biggy nothing happens since I do not execute `calculateSum()` if a Space or letter are entered. Look at my answer, there is validation happening to prevent this.